# URL query string guessing

Tags: http, tools, url

I have recently identified a controller that handles query string parameters that are not obvious, by simply guessing query string parameters. E.g.

```
http://domain.com/controller.php?guessed_param=18
```

Is there a tool that takes a base URL and builds several variants from it with common query string parameters?

Comment: [F12] > Console > paste `for(i=0;i<100;i++) new Image().src="?guessed_param="+i;` [Enter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at something like [Burp suite](https://portswigger.net/)'s intruder feature for this. that can easily create a variety of URLs from a base, and includes preset lists.

Another option would be to look at [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) which is a similar application.

Comment: 2nd OWASP ZAP. It's free and very easy to use for stuff like this.